# How to display and fix find the actual error being registered

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple delete button code on a form to delete records in a table. When the button is clicked it throws the message that there is no record to delete

The form is set to allow edits, additions, and deletions.

```vb
Private Sub DeleteRecord_Click()
    If MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure?", Buttons:=vbYesNo, title:="Delete") = vbYes Then
        On Error Resume Next
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            MsgBox Prompt:="Deleted", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Deleted"
        Else
            MsgBox Prompt:="There is no record to delete.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Cancelled", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Canceled"
    End If
End Sub
```

I expected the record to be deleted but the message says no record exists, If I refresh the record does indeed still exist. I am not sure where my error is here.

Comment: I tested code and works perfect for me.

Comment: @HansUp the message returned when I remove On error resume next is runtime 2046 "deleterecord isn't available now".

Comment: @HansUp its a query based upon a table, but when I looked at the source in the properties box it wasn't defined. it was empty, could that be a factor?

Comment: @HansUp, the form is used to edit existing purchase orders, or in some cases delete them.. It is the parent table to 1 or 2 child tables as well.

Comment: @HansUp, yes I can successfully edit from this form. That's part of my confusion. I didn't write the code but I don't see anything changing it's source at run time. However the edits go directly to the child tables and the delete would affect the parent table.

Comment: @HansUp, upon a closer look I am seeing that some of the data when this form is populated comes from other tables, I see 3 different sources.

Comment: @HansUp, I think you've hit on it there. As I just figured out there are more sources for the information than the parent table. I'm going to take a look at the referential integrity settings on these relationships.  Thanks, I'll let you know if that was it.

Comment: @HansUp, OK, the form is split, there are 3 tables feeding the data. The editing which works applies to a child table but the delete would apply to the parent and referential integrity is fully enforced. I guess my next question is do I have to rewrite this to allow the delete command to apply to the parent table [PurchaseOrders] directly?

Comment: @HansUp, yes it allows me to delete

Comment: @HansUp that would be ideal, unfortunately he no longer works here. It fell to me and I am still learning as I go. It seems logical to me that if I can target the delete command to the right table using some code that should do the trick. Am I on the right track with that line of thinking?

Comment: @HansUp, I gotta wrap it up for today, it's been a long one. I can shoot out the file tomorrow with a link. Thanks

Comment: @HansUp, I didn't mean to just disappear, I had a few other issues to deal with. I got permission to post a stripped down version of the database to get some help with it but I created some additional issues I haven't had time to deal with so I haven't moved any further on it.

Comment: @HansUp, Thanks for the help. I have been asked to remove the delete button from the form so all the problems I was having have been solved so to speak. I appreciate the help none the less

Answer (score 0):

This should catch the error, display the error number as well as the error description in a dialog box. You can also add any error handling you need into errorReceived as well. Good luck!

```
Private Sub DeleteRecord_Click()
    On Error GoTo errorReceived
    If MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure?", Buttons:=vbYesNo, title:="Delete") = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="Deleted", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="There is no record to delete.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Error"
    End If
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Cancelled", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, title:="Canceled"
    End If
    Exit Sub

    errorReceived:
        MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
        'Add error handling here
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the bit of code there. It does show the problem in a message box as you said unfortunately I am no closer to solving my issue. The message is something I already discovered as I stepped through and followed the suggestions given to me in the thread above.

Comment: the message box show error code 2046. DeleteRecord not available right now

Comment: No problem. Is there any possibility that on your form the toolbar has been disabled? Also, has the data on the record been edited at all? I believe both of these things can cause this issue.

Comment: The navigation buttons and record selectors are both disabled but I did try to enable them to see if that changed the results and it did not. As far as the data goes the error message is the same whether it's dirty or clean

Comment: Interesting. Could you try getting the ID of the current record, then use that to delete it directly with a query? Like: `CurrentDb.Execute("DELETE * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE PurchaseOrders.ID = " & currentRecordId & ";")`

Comment: I just tried this 'CurrentDb.Execute ("DELETE * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE [PurchaseOrders].[PONum] = " & Me.txtPO & ";")' with no luck. I get a data mismatch error

Comment: In your DB what is the data type of PONum? If it is a string you'll need to add single quotes to your query: `CurrentDb.Execute ("DELETE * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE [PurchaseOrders].[PONum] = '" & Me.txtPO & "';")` around `" & Me.txtPO & "`

Comment: Any luck, Rats?

Comment: Not so far, however my manager at this point has asked me to consider taking this delete button off the form and making the deletion of this item (a P.O.) something that is done only by admin anyhow. Not sure which direction it will ultimately go yet.

Comment: It's official. No more delete button but I appreciate your help on what I was trying to achieve